# NUnit: Global setup fixture not used when fixture to run is specified on command line

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a unit test assembly, using NUnit, that contains thousands of tests in various namespaces and fixtures.

I want to run some global setup before any tests in my assembly are run (configuring Trace listeners). I can do this by creating a `[SetUpFixture]` in the global namespace.

This works fine when running all tests e.g.:
`nunit.exe testassembly.exe`

However, if I specify a fixture to test, then the global setup is not run, e.g.:
`nunit.exe testassembly.exe /fixture=MyTests`

How do I provide global setup that is always run before any tests in an assembly are run?

**UPDATE:**

Note that the console test runner will work fine using the `/run` option, i.e. global setup is run even when only a particular test fixture is run. I'm after a solution for the GUI test runner.

Comment: Which version of NUnit you are using?

Comment: @sllev - NUnit 2.5.5. Also tested with the latest stable release 2.5.10.11092.

Comment: Post your question as an answer, it helped me.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski - I'll post someone else's answer instead, hopefully that will help you too :)

Answer (score 7):

Charlie Poole suggested an alternative in the [NUnit discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nunit-discuss/fmLWgxI-cDM/discussion).

The recommended workaround is to include all setup and teardown at the fixture level using using `[TestFixtureSetup]` and `[TestFixtureTearDown]`.

Global setup and teardown can be achieved like this by using a base class for the test fixtures to share code between fixtures. For global setup meant to be run once only before any fixture, a flag can be used to prevent it being executed multiple times.

P.S. The /fixture option is deprecated theses days.